# What's the difference between regex [-+]? and (-|+)?

Tags: regex

What's the difference between regex

```
[-+]?
```

and

```
(-|+)?
```

Don't they mean the same?

Comment: I don't want to ruin the mood, but [this might be a good helper](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)

Comment: Alma & HamZa, do you like apples?

Comment: @LievenCardoen no, I like windows or linux :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both match same characters. But the second form produce capturing group. You can use backreference to access the group (`\1` or `$1`, .. according to your regular expression engine).

**UPDATE**

The second form is invalid in many regular expression engines. (valid for some old regular expression engine that match `+` match literally).

Because `+` has special meaning: One or more repetitions of preceding pattern, but there's nothing to repeat.

Comment: Got it from Flex/Bison book. Don't know why they use both regex's next to each other (without using a backreference)...

Answer (score 2):

They are same but I would prefer character class (1st form) since 2nd form captures `-` or `+` which you may not need.

Even this will be equivalent without capturing the text in the group:

```
(?:-|+)?
```

Answer (score -2):

Most regexes can be put in the form of alternation groups and the star operator - for example, `[ab]+` can be written as `(a|b)(a|b)*` - but this is much more verbose, so the other operators exist. You included the question mark operator in your regex, but really `[-+]?` is equivalent to `(+|-|)`

So there really is no difference (except for capturing as others have mentioned), but that doesn't mean the other operators aren't useful in making a regex compact and intuitive to understand.