# REGEX - (?:'|") versus ['"] -> same effect or there are differences?

Tags: regex

Effectively, the regex codes:

```
A) (?:'|")
B) ['"]
```

would do/act/result the same thing or are there some small differences between one and the other?

Note: There is another question slightly similar with this one located here:
[What's the difference between regex [-+]? and (-|+)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118964/whats-the-difference-between-regex-and)
but my case differs from that other one because it is not considering the capturing group nor the optional **?** for each option. It is more straight forward in the comparison of (?:) versus [].

Comment: will do the same job..

Comment: Yes, they are the same.  Assume that the speed difference between the two is irrelevant.  Choose the one that more clearly illustrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndyLester: They are the same in theoretical regular expression, but on a regex engine that doesn't transforms `(?:'|")` to character class, `(?:'|")` can cause extra backtracking and reduce performance.

Comment: In my case the speed is irrelevant and they are not going to show up all the time, but I was worried they could end up causing bugs.
Also, option A) is visually better to maintain and that is a super plus, while option B) is the worst case scenario! Is that ' plus " or 3 '? What was that developer thinking??? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there some small differences between one and the other?

1. The first one is longer than the second one.
2. The first one is called an non-capturing group while the other is called character class.

> same effect or are there any differences?

Character class is **slightly** *faster* than the non-capturing group<sup>*</sup> Other than that, there is no difference whatsoever when functionality is concerned.

<sup>*</sup> Based on tests run more than twice located at http://jsperf.com/non-capturing-group-vs-character-class